# chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener - reports changeInfo.status == 'complete' immediately

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

My extension is for Facebook. It logs tab state changes correctly on the first load, but if I navigate to another page through a link on the current page, then it reports changeinfo.status == 'complete' immediately on the click.

I can not find anything to suggest I've made a mistake

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(check);


function check(tab_id, changeinfo, tab){
    console.log("tab change: " + changeinfo.status);
    // make sure the page is done loading
    if ( !(tab.url !== undefined && changeinfo.status == "complete")) {
        return;
    }
    if(tab.url.match(/facebook.com\/[^\/]*$/)){ //if the url of the tab matches a certain website 
        chrome.pageAction.show(tab_id); //show the icon (by default it is not shown).

        console.log("accepted state: " + changeinfo.status);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try with [webNavigation API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation) if it fit your needs

**manifest**

```
"permissions": ["webNavigation"]
```

**background script**

```
chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(function(details) {
  if (details.url.startsWith('https://www.facebook.com/')) {
    chrome.pageAction.show(details.tabId); 
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't made a mistake, facebook loads it's content dynamically. They change the URL without reloading using `history.pushState`  from the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History).

I don't think you can get the information you need using `tabs.onUpdated` since the status 'complete' is actually correct from it's perspective. You might have to deal with this in your content script.